# define a variable in absence of #ifdef preprocessor

Tags: java

I have C++ background. Somewhere in the middle of my a java project I need to define a variable whose type depends on a boolean value(which I had defined earlier)
can I do this:

```
if(Main.NEW_STYLE)
            ArrayList<LogFileLine> lineBuffer = new ArrayList<LogFileLine>();
        else
            ArrayList<String> lineBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
```

if not, what is the solution please?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a raw type (just `ArrayList`), but I **strongly** discourage that as raw types only exist for backwards compatibility with pre-generic code.

The appropriate solution would probably be to encapsulate that list into an interface and have two separate implementation classes (and choose the implementation class based on the boolean value).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it will not help you much. Because the scope of those `ArrayList` is the body of the if statement.

You could do the following:

```
ArrayList<Object> lineBuffer;
if(Main.NEW_STYLE) lineBuffer = new ArrayList<LogFileLine>();
else lineBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then cast your Objects accordingly. The other way would be to create a container interface, which will then be the type of your `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<LogInterface> lineBuffer = new ArrayList<LogInterface>();
lineBuffer.add(new LogInterface_LogFileLine(aLogFileLine));
lineBuffer.add(new LogInterface_String("lalelu"));
```

You would then implement two versions of the `LogInterface`, one holding a `String` (`LogInterface_String`), the other one holding a `LogFileLine` (`LogInterface_LogFileLine`).

BUT, since you named your boolean `NEW_STYLE`, I guess it will somewhen replace the "old style" completely, so I would recommend doing the first suggestion from me. You will have to then do this `if (Main.NEW_STYLE) ; else ;` everywhere you access your `lineBuffer`. But it will be much easier to kick the old stuff out once you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create an interface capturing what methods you rely on from `String` and from `LogFileLine`. Call it `LogLine` or something, which is implemented by two different classes, `StringLogLine` and `FileLogLine`, and then do

```
List<LogStyle> lineBuffer = new ArrayList<LogLine>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have compiler preprocessors.

I believe you are trying to have an ArrayList at the end of this statement. So here's how you should do it:

```
ArrayList lineBuffer;
if (...)
    lineBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
else
    lineBuffer = new ArrayList<LogFileLine>();

lineBuffer.add(something);
```

However `add` might cause runtime problems, so why don't you just do

`ArrayList lineBuffer = new ArrayList<Object>()`

which  basically can keep anything?

Comment: That's using a raw type (`ArrayList`) and that's almost always a bad idea (except when you need it for backwards compatibility).